# How to get the last object in a generic list?

Tags: c#, generics, iqueryable

I am passing a populated SelectList to my View and I want to default the selected value to the **last** record in the list.  So far I've got:

```
IQueryable<BuildNumber> projBuildNos = tcRepository.GetProjectBuildNos();
BuildList = new SelectList(projBuildNos, "ID", "value", projBuildNos.Last().ID);
```

I get an exception saying "the query operator 'Last' is not supported but I can't seem to get at the last record in my generic list and can't find any examples.

This code is from a 'form view model' passing select lists from my repository back to the view and I think I should be performing this here.  However I'm new to generics/mvc/linq so am happy for alternative suggestions.

Thanks in advance for any help.  Please let me know if you want any more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you already going to suck all the results from your query into memory? If so, I suggest you execute your query and get the result into a list:

```
List<BuildNumber> projBuildNos = tcRepository.GetProjectBuildNos().ToList();
BuildList = new SelectList(projBuildNos, "ID", "value", projBuildNos.Last().ID);
```

Otherwise you could easily end up with a workaround which executes the query twice - possibly giving inconsistent results.

Comment: Yeah I'm populating the SelectList so I'm using all of the result set.   That did the trick, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I found this on MSDN:

[Queryable.LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb504095.aspx) -- Returns the last element in a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Might this involve another call to the db? If so, I figure I've got all the data there so just want to grab the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
projBuildNos.Reverse().First().ID
```